# Checkout latest version of a file

Tags: git

How can I checkout the latest version of a particular file from the remote branch?

Comment: You cannot check out single files with git. Just cloning the repository should give you access to any version of the file though.

Answer (score 4):

First make sure get the latest version, type `git fetch`.

Then you can use `git checkout origin/master <file_name>`. (Assume you want the file in `master` branch)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the latest committed version of a file, locally:

```
git checkout file.txt
```

Or if you need the latest remote version of a file. I believe this fetches all remote branches, but you'll be on master locally.

```
git checkout master
git fetch
```

See all versions of file.txt:

```
git log --oneline --branches file.txt
```

The latest version of file.txt could be on a branch besides master. Since `git log file.txt` only searches the current branch, I added `--branches`. If the latest version was on another branch, then checkout that branch. Or checkout the id of the individual commit you want, like `git checkout f823772`.

With `git log` you can also specifiy `--remotes=somewhere` which might be helpful too.